# Insert into a table and select the id from last inserted row

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hellow everyone! im trying to write a query that inserts data into a table and extracts the last inserted row's id. Is it possible to do that in the same query?

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Song (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    artistName VARCHAR(26),
    genre TEXT, 
    releaseDate DATE
)
```

What i've tried with:

```
INSERT INTO Song (title, artistName, genre, releaseDate) 
VALUES("Shape of you", "Ed Sheeran", "Pop", datetime('now', 'localtime'))
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Comment: What is the issue with your code?

Comment: No, you have to execute `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` after the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your rows by the `id` column and extract the last one like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Song ORDER BY "id" DEC LIMIT 1;
```

This will give you the last inserted row based on the `id` column.